# PHP mysql return parameter when query result == true

Tags: php, mysql

In php I call a procedure in mysql. Now I want to check if a query `result == true` then set return variable in my php file in true or false if query failed. How can I do that?

This is my php code:

```
public function DeleteSingleAccount($accountId)
{
        $Config = new Config();
        $mysqli = $Config->OpenConnection();            
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "CALL DeleteSingleAccount($accountId)") or die("Query fail: ". mysqli_error());
}
```

This is my query in mysql for now:

```
DELETE 
    FROM table
        WHERE accountId = par_AccountId
```

This code runs correct but I want to set an return parameter when query is true or false.

Comment: What do you actually want to check? Whether a row was deleted, that the query executed or that the query was valid at all?

Comment: Assign the query like this: `$result = mysqli_query...` and the you can check it like this: `if($result){ echo "win"; } else { echo "fail"; }` (BTW: it can return true, but doesn't mean it has any row's init)

Answer (score 1):

```
public function DeleteSingleAccount($accountId)
{
    $Config = new Config();
    $mysqli = $Config->OpenConnection();            
    return !! mysqli_query($mysqli, "CALL DeleteSingleAccount(" . intval($accountId) . ")");
}
```

I added intval() to avoid SQL injection (not needed if you're sure $accountId is always an integer, never null, empty string, user input, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Think your looking for something like this:

```
public function DeleteSingleAccount($accountId) {
    $Config = new Config();
    $mysqli = $Config->OpenConnection();            
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "CALL DeleteSingleAccount($accountId)") or die("Query fail: ". mysqli_error());
   //^Assignment of the query to a variable

    if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
     //^Check if query is successfull      ^ Check if query has 1 or more rows in it! (You can delete this check if you don't care about how many row's the result has)
        echo "The query is successful and have 1 or more rows in it!";
    } else {
        echo "The query failed or have 0 rows in it!";
    }

}
```